# How to capture significant increases in one category("class") but not the rest?

Tags: r

[image]

Let's say I have like 300 probes. For Probe 1, you can see the treatment effect on Class 2 but not the others. In probe2, we can see treatment effects in both Class2 and Class3 which is no good. Out of the 300 probes, I would like to find a pattern (specificity) like probe 1 (effects on one class but not the other).

What kind of method/metrics/models can I use? I'm new to statistics/DS and my main language is R so if you can direct me to the library or function that'll be great too.

Comment: What is meant by: "you can see the treatment effect"? Are the others hidden from the researcher? What are the different classes? Why are there two doses for class 2? What means "which is no good", what metric are you referring to? Do you want to find the probes where there is a large difference between the treatment effects of different classes?

Comment: Let's say the classes are different cell lines. And there can be different dosage values like 500 nm, 700 nm, etc. Ideally, I'd like to find probes where there's an increasing effect on one cell line but not any of the other. Large difference between treatment effects of different classes is good too.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you already know the treatment effects (i.e. you already have the data for those plots you have posted) but you have 300 probes and you want an automatic way of finding those where the largest effect is also more or less the only larger effect.

In this case, I would suggest computing for each probe the [standard score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) of the largest effect $e_{max}$: compute the mean $\mu_e$ and standard deviation $S_e$ of the effects and then compute:
$$
z_{max} = \frac{e_{max}-\mu_e}{S_e},
$$
which is the distance to the mean in units of the standard deviation and gives you a comparable measure of how much $e_{max}$ "sticks out".
This leaves you with as many standard scores $z_{max}$ as there are probes and then you can just pick those with the largest ones.

Of course, you could also try other scores, e.g., denoting the second largest effect as $e_{sl}$ you could try as score:
$$
s = \frac{e_{max}-e_{sl}}{e_{max} - \mu_e},
$$
which would make sure the relative distance between the largest and second-largest is especially large.

Comment: Thank you @frank.  I appreciate your answer and the z(max) works to an extent. However, it becomes problematic with large treatment effects. For example, on the top z(max) score, in my data, the treatment effect for cell-line 1 is 16x however we can see a 3x treatment effect in cell-line 2. Ideally, I would like to find probes where cell-line 2 would have <2x or no treatment effect. Also, would it account for the different dosages? For example 500nm would have 5x and 700nm would have 7x, however it would skew the mean(e) in your example.

Comment: Please make sure to include all constraints in your question.